# Copying date Word to Excel - wrong format

Tags: excel, vba, date, ms-word, format

I have been trying to solve an issue I have with copying dates from Word document to Excel using VBA.

My issue is the format.  If I put `dd/MM/yyyy` it will change during the process to `MM/dd/yyyy` and I cannot solve the issue.

Basically for copying I am using this line:

```
Sheets("wImp").Range("AA" & i) = wdDoc.ContentControls(1).Range.Text
```

However during the process the data is modified.

I originally used **LegacyForms** but it did work and I hoped **Date Picker** would help but it does not.  And in a case the date is impossible to switch like `21/12/2017` it will stay as it should.  But when it can be switched like `1/5/2017` it will be switched to `5/1/2017`.
!!! Nevertheless the cell format stays `dd/MM/yyyy` for all the dates, but the months and days position is switched.

See below for what I have as input in Word and the output in Excel.

Word:

[image: Word]

Excel:

[image: Excel]

Comment: What date format do you normally use on your computer?

Comment: I use dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: If you now change (temporarily) the three Excel cells to `General` format, do they all become 5 digit numbers, or do some still appear as dates?  (If they aren't really dates - just text that looks like a date - they will stay as they are.  But real dates will show the serial day number when changed to `General` format.  Knowing which are dates and which are text might give more information re what part of the process is causing the issue.)

Comment: If I change all the cells to `general` only 1st one `05/01/2017` will be as 5digit number `42740`, other two stay as dates - `21/12/2017` and `13/09/2017`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the continental date format `"dd/mm/yyyy"` in your sheet you must use `Format()` function.  So, try this:

```
Sheets("wImp").Range("AA" & i) = Format(wdDoc.ContentControls(1).Range.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")
Sheets("wImp").Range("AA" & i).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

[Oficial documentation of Format() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer! However, if I change it to your proposal the result in excel is completely the same.

Comment: Well, I added a line in order to set the format to the range of cells.

Comment: Yeah, changing the format to correct one does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "01/05/2017"

ActiveSheet.Range("A2").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = "01/05/2017"

ActiveSheet.Range("A3").NumberFormat = "yyyy/m/d;@"
ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = "01/05/2017"

End Sub
```

Try something like this.
Excel will convert the data during copy.
So, change "NumberFormat" before copy.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a string to the cell makes Excel think that the string should be interpreted in a `"mm/dd/yyyy"` format irrespective of your locale (and irrespective of the cell's date format).

So convert the string to a `Date` using the `CDate` function (which will be done using your system date/time settings) before assigning the value to the cell.

```
Sheets("wImp").Range("AA" & i) = CDate(wdDoc.ContentControls(1).Range.Text)
```

That date can then be displayed in whatever date format you want to use for the cell.

Comment: I salute you! Works on a first try! I have to test it, in case there is some weird case. Anyhow, thank you very much for a help and your time!

Comment: @JiříJezdinský And I learnt something new - I hadn't realised that it was so USA-centric when assigning a date from a string like that.  It might explain a lot of the other date-related issues that I have come across.